# Android application name on two lines

Tags: android

How can I display the app name on two lines.

I have tried:

`<string name="app_name">"Application\n\rName"</string>`

It is not a duplicate question. I am testing it on Android 4.3 and it won't work with `\n`, `\\n` or `\n\r`

Comment: App name on two lines where? `ActionBar`?

Comment: No. Under the icon, before starting application. It is Android 4.3 and it won't work with \n, \\n or \n\r